# Clojure: memory leaks using eval

Tags: clojure

My application evaluates quoted expressions received from remote clients. Overtime, my system's memory increases and eventually it crashes. What I've found out is that:

When I execute the following code from Clojure's nrepl in a docker container:

```
(dotimes [x 1000000] ; or some arbitrary large number
 (eval '(+ 1 1)))
```

the container's memory usage keeps rising until it hits the limit, at which point the system will crash.

How do I get around this problem?
There's another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608685/clojure-application-leaks-memory-using-eval) mentioning this behavior. One of the answers mentions the use of `tools.reader`, which still uses `eval` if I need code execution, leading to the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to get around this as each call to `eval` creates a new class, even though the form you're evaluating is exactly the same. By itself, JVM will not get rid of new classes.

There are two ways to circumvent this:

- Stop using `eval` altogether (by e.g. creating your own DSL or your own version of `eval` with limited functionality) or at least use it less frequently, e.g. by batching the forms you need to evaluate
- Unload already loaded classes - I haven't done it myself and it probably requires a lot of work, but you can follow answers in this topic: [Unloading classes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java)

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "By itself, JVM will not get rid of new classes" -> see my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I delved a bit deeper and seems like the truth is somewhere in between. My statement is correct. However, `eval` creates a new classloader every time, and those do get eventually GC'ed along with all the classes that were loaded by it. Why it can sometimes lead to OOM, I do not know.

Comment: Right, every top-level form creates a new classloader and GC doesn't seem to (typically) have problems getting rid of those. I remember there might be something specific to nREPL although I do not know if that's applicable here: "In a nREPL client, instances of DynamicClassLoader keep piling up." (see https://danielsz.github.io/blog/2021-05-12T13_24.html)

Comment: A third option: replace your usage of eval with https://github.com/babashka/sci, it does not suffer from the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how `eval` exactly works internally,
but based on my observations I don't think your conclusions are correct and also Eugene's remark "By itself, JVM will not get rid of new classes" seems to be false.

[I run your sample with -Xmx256m and it went fine](https://github.com/jumarko/clojure-experiments/commit/824f3a69019840940eaa88c3427515bcba33c4d2).

```
  (time (dotimes [x 1000000] ; or some arbitrary large number
          (eval '(+ 1 1))))
  ;; "Elapsed time: 529079.032449 msecs"
```

I checked [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608685/clojure-application-leaks-memory-using-eval) and they say it's *Metaspace* that is growing not heap.
So I observed the Metaspace and it's usage is growing but *also shrinking*.

You can find my experiment here together with some graphs from JMC console: https://github.com/jumarko/clojure-experiments/commit/824f3a69019840940eaa88c3427515bcba33c4d2

Note: To run this experiment, I've used JDK 17.0.2 on macOS